# For which $\alpha$ does this system of equations spiral towards the orgin?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I am stuck with a math problem and I hope that somebody could help me in the right direction.

Question:

For which values of $\alpha$ do the trajectories of the solutions of the systems $x^{\prime}=A x$ spiral towards the orgin?

\begin{equation}
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
\alpha & -2
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

The first step I took was to calculate the eigenvalues, by obtaining first the characteristic value:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&(1-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)-2 \alpha=0 \\
&-2-\lambda+2 \lambda+\lambda^{2}-2 \alpha=0 \\
&-\lambda^{2}+\lambda-2 \alpha-2=0 \\
&\lambda^{2}+\lambda+(-2 \alpha-2)=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

With the eigen values

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{9+8 \alpha}}{2},-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{9+8 \alpha}}{2}
\end{equation}

Here I made the assumption that the eigen vectors need to be imaginary in order to be able to spiral. To make the eigenvalue imaginary, the part under the root should become smaller than zero. Solving this results in $\alpha < -9/8$.

To state the condition that the spiral needs to spiral towards the orgin we use:

\begin{equation}
|\lambda|<1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}<1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{|9+8 \alpha|}\right)^{2}}<1
\end{equation}

From the latter, we calculate that $\alpha$ should be bigger than $-3/2$ and smaller than $-1$ to meet this requirement.

The answer, for which $\alpha$ the spiral will spiral to the orgin is therefore a range of values between $-3/2$ and $-9/8$.

The solution manual states that the answer is smaller than $-9/8$. Therefore, something is not right. Could I please get feedback on this?

Addition (25-05):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Do you also know what the meaning is of \begin{equation}
|\lambda|<1
\end{equation}?

Comment: Dear Andreas, I edited the thread with an screenshot with one of my lecture slides. This indicates that the eigenvalue has a meaning for the stability of the system. From my perspective there is a conflict between the slides and your answers. There is a large change that I misunderstand the slide, could you please give feedback on this?

Comment: The lecture slides discuss discrete-time systems, i.e., $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. From the notation of your question, I was assuming a continuous-time system, i.e., $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}x(t) = Ax(t)$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. If the task really assumes a discrete-time system, your solution looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two-dimensional discrete-time linear system $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$ spirals towards the origin, if $\mathrm{Im}(\lambda) \neq 0$ and $|\lambda|<1$ for both Eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$.

Hence, your solution is correct and the solution provided by the manual seems to neglect that $|\lambda|<1$ is necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help